# REST APIs: How to POST several entries from a (JSON) file in a python loop?

Tags: python, json, api, rest

I am new in python and REST world.

**My Python script**

```
import json
import requests

with open(r"create-multiple-Users.json", "r") as payload:
    data = json.load(payload)
    json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

    for i in range(len(data)):
        r = requests.post('http://localhost:3000/users',
                          data=json_data, headers=headers)
```

**Mock API server**: https://github.com/typicode/json-server .

**Entry file:** "info.json" with **Endpoint:** /users that has one user initially.

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John",
      "job": "Wong"
    }
   ]
}
```

**Issue:**

- POSTing from a file with only one user works perfectly. The new user is appended to info.json as expected as an object.
- **But** when trying to POST let's say 3 users from file "create-multiple-Users.json" below, then the users are appended to the "info.json" as lists of objects 3 times (i.e. the number of objects/iterations)

  [
  {
  "id": 10,
  "name": "Janet",
  "job": "Weaver"
  },
  {
  "id": 12,
  "name": "Kwonn",
  "job": "Wingtsel"
  },
  {
  "id": 13,
  "name": "Eve",
  "job": "Holt"
  }
  ]

I would expect the users to be appended one by one as separate objects.

Maybe I am too oversimplifying the looping?
Any help is highly appreciated.

PS: Sorry I couldn't get the multiple-users file formatted ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using the hint thanks to **"enriqueojedalara"**

```
import json
import requests

with open(r"create-multiple-Users.json", "r") as payload:
    data = json.load(payload) #<class 'list'>
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
    print("Total number of objects: ", len(data))
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data_new = json.dumps(data[i])
        r = requests.post('http://localhost:3000/users', data=data_new, headers=headers)
        print("Item#", i, "added", " -> ", data_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple change in your for iteration would help:

```py
import json
import requests

with open(r"create-multiple-Users.json", "r") as payload:
    data = json.load(payload)
    json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

    for row in data: # Change this to iterate the json list
        r = requests.post('http://localhost:3000/users',
                          data=row, headers=headers) # Send row that is a single object
```